# Why is eclipse complaining when I try to close BufferedReader in finally block?

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, bufferedreader, try-catch-finally

Here is my code:

```
public static String readFile()
    {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line;
        String dump="";

        try
        {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dbDumpTest.txt"));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fnfex)
        {
            System.out.println(fnfex.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }

        try
        {
            while( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                dump += line + "\r\n";
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage() + " Error reading file");
        }
        finally
        {
            br.close();
        }
        return dump;
```

So eclipse is complaining about an unhandled IO exception caused by `br.close();`

Why would this cause an IO exception?

My second question is why eclipse doesn't complain about the following code:

```
InputStream is = null; 
      InputStreamReader isr = null;
      BufferedReader br = null;

      try{
         // open input stream test.txt for reading purpose.
         is = new FileInputStream("c:/test.txt");

         // create new input stream reader
         isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

         // create new buffered reader
         br = new BufferedReader(isr);

         // releases any system resources associated with reader
         br.close();

         // creates error
         br.read();

      }catch(IOException e){

         // IO error
         System.out.println("The buffered reader is closed");
      }finally{

         // releases any system resources associated
         if(is!=null)
            is.close();
         if(isr!=null)
            isr.close();
         if(br!=null)
            br.close();
      }
   }
}
```

I'd appreciate it if you kept the explanation in Laymen's terms if possible. Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) would simplify the code significantly.

Comment: It complains, alright. I suspect the method the second code comes from has a `throws` declaration. Or that there is a `try...catch` around this code. Share the complete method, please.

Comment: Unless you're hiding something, the second snippet should have the same issue about unhandled `IOException`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both code examples should have compiler errors complaining about an unhandled IOException.  Eclipse shows these as errors in both code examples for me.

The reason is that the `close` method throws an `IOException`, a checked exception, when called in the `finally` block, which is outside a `try` block.

The fix is to use a [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), which is available in Java 1.7+.  The resources declared are implicitly closed.

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dbDumpTest.txt")))
{
   // Your br processing code here
}
catch (IOException e)
{
   // Your handling code here
}
// no finally necessary.
```

Prior to Java 1.7, you need to wrap the calls to `close()` in their own try-catch blocks inside the `finally` block.  It's a lot of verbose code to ensure that everything is closed and cleaned up.

```
finally
{
    try{ if (is != null) is.close(); } catch (IOException ignored) {}
    try{ if (isr != null) isr.close(); } catch (IOException ignored) {}
    try{ if (br != null) br.close(); } catch (IOException ignored) {}
}
```

Comment: So after the code within the try block is executed, the BufferedReader I declared in the try-with-resources statement closes automatically??

Comment: Yes, that is the point of try-with-resources.  From the link I used above: "The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement."